# Why can a new C# MemoryCache access another cache's objects?

Tags: c#, caching

The behavior of the C# MemoryCache is making some of my unit tests fail. When a new MemoryCache object is created, it can still access objects added to a different memory cache. Does anyone know why this is the case?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ObjectCache cache1 = MemoryCache.Default;

        object myObject = new object();

        CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        cacheItemPolicy.SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0);
        cache1.Add("My Object", myObject, cacheItemPolicy);

        ObjectCache cache2 = MemoryCache.Default;

        object cachedObject = cache2.Get("My Object");
    }
```

The cached object returned from cache2 is the one added to cache1.

Comment: `cache1` and `cache2` are both `MemoryCache.Default`. You haven't created anything new.

Comment: Code shown does not demonstrate "a new MemoryCache object is created" at all. It is possible you've posted wrong code - please [edit] post and make sure to post correct code. (You may also want to read on what assignment does in C# if you believe `cache2 = MemoryCache.Default` creates new instance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've never created a MemoryCache in the code you've posted. What you have done however, is declare variables that reference MemoryCache.Default by the names of `cache1` and `cache2`. To demonstrate this, you can always use the `ReferenceEquals` method. As you can see, the following code will print "True" showing that they both reference `MemoryCache.Default`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Your code, from the original post
    ObjectCache cache1 = MemoryCache.Default;
    object myObject = new object();
    CacheItemPolicy cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
    cacheItemPolicy.SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0);
    cache1.Add("My Object", myObject, cacheItemPolicy);
    ObjectCache cache2 = MemoryCache.Default;
    object cachedObject = cache2.Get("My Object");

    //Test the reference, output the result
    Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(cache1, cache2)); //Outputs True
}
```